# show custom posts on front page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, frontpage

I have set a special category for posts that I want to show on the front page here: http://aquadiva.it/en/

some of them won't show though. there should be four.

I suspect the problem lies in the fact that two of the four posts are custom posts.  The category itself works, because, if I search for category, what it gives is those four posts: http://aquadiva.it/en/category/frontpage/
while on the front page I have only the ones belonging to "regular" posts (articles) and not to custom posts (products).

this is my content-frontpage.php:

```
<?php

$nirvanas = nirvana_get_theme_options();
foreach ($nirvanas as $key => $value) { ${"$key"} = $value; } ?>

    <section id="container" class="one-column <?php //echo nirvana_get_layout_class(); ?>">

        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php //cryout_before_content_hook();

        $nirvana_old_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

        if ( have_posts() ) :

            /* Start the Loop */
            update_option( 'posts_per_page', $nirvanas['nirvana_frontpostscount']);

            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$nirvanas['nirvana_frontpostscount'],'paged'=> $paged) ); 
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

                global $more; $more=0; 
                get_template_part( 'content/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

            if($nirvana_pagination=="Enable") nirvana_pagination($the_query->max_num_pages); else nirvana_content_nav( 'nav-below' );

        else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No Posts to Display', 'nirvana' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php printf(
                        __( 'You currently have no published posts. To hide this message either <a href="%s">add some posts</a> or disable displaying posts on the Presentation Page in <a href="%s">theme settings</a>.', 'nirvana' ),
                        esc_url( admin_url()."post-new.php"),
                        esc_url( admin_url()."themes.php?page=nirvana-page") ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php
        endif;
        update_option( 'posts_per_page', $nirvana_old_posts_per_page);
        //cryout_after_content_hook();
        ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    <?php //nirvana_get_sidebar(); ?>
    </section><!-- #container -->
```

what can I do?

Comment: is 'products' a post type or category?

Comment: you can also just add this to your content-frontpage -> 
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'frontpage'
);
so - $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$nirvanas['nirvana_frontpostscount'],'paged'=> $paged, 'category_name'=>'frontpage') );

Comment: a custom post type

Answer (score 0):

Exchange this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$nirvanas['nirvana_frontpostscount'],'paged'=> $paged) );
```

with this:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$nirvanas['nirvana_frontpostscount'],'paged'=> $paged, 'category_name'=>'frontpage', 'post_type' => array('post','product')) );
```

Let me know if this works. If not, let me know what the name of your custom post type is.

Comment: What is the name of your custom post type? Is it 'product' ?

Comment: If it is indeed 'product' and I'm pretty sure it is, try my updated code in the answer, it is now set to query both 'posts' and 'products'

Comment: no. it does not. not even with what Stender suggested ($args = array( 'category_name' => 'frontpage' );).  My custom post type name is "product". Thank you.

Comment: you don't have that ";" there at the end do you?

Comment: I do have that ";". should I take it out? @stender

Comment: In my eyes, it should be exactly copy pasted from @LLs answer -

Comment: ok. now that part looks like this: "... $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$nirvanas['nirvana_frontpostscount'],'paged'=> $paged, 'category_name'=>'frontpage', 'post_type' => array('post','product')) );  
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ..."